# MantisBT: How to set default filter of "Assign to" to myself?

Tags: mantis

I want to set default value for "assigned to" filter in `view_all_bug_page.php` to myself. How can I do this?

In fact, I want when my users going to see `view_all_bug_page.php`, (by default) viewing his/her "assigned to" works, not all works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known feature request from 2006 (see [here](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=7525)) and at the moment not possible without changing the source code (which I'd not recommend).

You could create a public filter with the settings you've described and your users could then use this filter. The problem: the filter will reset after discarding the mantis cookies (as far as I know).

By the way, what's wrong with `-> My View -> Assigned to Me (Unresolved)`? It's just one mouse click more to go. ;)